# How to get the shortest array shape in a python numpy multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, shapes

If I have a multidimensional numpy array like:

```
>> x = np.array([
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
    np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
])

>> x.shape
(5,)
```

Is there a "pythonic way" to find the shortest `shape` of arrays inside `x`?

Comment: `min(len(i) for i in x)` -> `4`

Comment: `numpy` isn't really designed for jagged arrays: it's meant more for things with consistent dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a solution based on [@chrisz comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046134/how-to-get-the-shortest-array-shape-in-a-python-numpy-multidimensional-array/50140146#comment87108548_50046134):

```
min(i.shape for i in x)
```

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need just the shortest array?

If yes I believe this is the easiest way

```
import numpy as np
l = []
 x = np.array([
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
])

for i in x:
    l.append(np.shape(i))
print (min(l))
```

Comment: sorry I did not copy my code carefully. I blame Jupyter!